# @Value annotation not getting resolved in Spring

Tags: java, spring

I saw a number of stackoverflow threads with the same topic but none resolved my issue. I am trying out for a simple spring application using annotation(I am aware with xml but not with annotation). Below is my code

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class Person {
@Value("Ducati")
private String bike;

public String getBike() {
    return bike;
}

public void setBike(String bike) {
    this.bike = bike;
}
}
```

Here the @Value annotation is not resolved. It is showing the error "Value cannot be resolved to a type". I know that @Value annotation is in the package "org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value". But I could not find the Value class inside this package in maven dependencies in eclipse. Below is my POM.xml

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.maven</groupId>
  <artifactId>SpringExp</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>SpringExp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.6</version>
        </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

I have tried using different spring version too. But none had the value class inside it. Please let me know what I am missing here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Spring didn't get support for annotations until 3.0.

Comment: Hi Nathan, thanks for the response. I have updated the spring version to the latest and the issue is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously I was using an older version of Spring which does not support the annotation. Updated the spring version in the pom to the latest version and the issue is resolved.